# How to use git's negative refspecs?

Tags: git, refs

I have a couple of remote branches (hotfixes) that I need to **not** fetch locally. I read about git negative refs but it seems like they are not working. They're supposed to work starting with git version 2.29. My current git version is 2.38.

This is my remote "origin" section in .git/config file:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
fetch = ^refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/2.14.439
fetch = ^refs/remotes/origin/hotfix/2.15.323
```

However, those two remote hotfix branches keep showing up locally on every pull. I do delete them before issuing a pull command. I tried `git pull -v` and I have no errors/warnings whatsoever, just clean output.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason not to fetch them? They should be extremely small.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+negative+refspec

Comment: `fetch = ^refs/heads/hotfix/2.14.439`